# Upcase method not returning upcased string

Tags: ruby

I keep getting false in these simple Ruby tests:

```
def large(string)
  if string.size > 20
    puts string.upcase!
  else
    puts string
  end
end
```

test:

```
p large("Hola vamos a la comida") == "HOLA VAMOS A LA COMIDA"
p large("Es hora de dormir") == "Es hora de dormir"
```

What is needed to make them work?

Comment: I see no reason for a downvote. It's a beginner question, for sure, but the problem description is understandable and it comes with a minimal, complete code sample. This is the sort of question behavior that should be upvoted!

Answer (score 4):

`puts` prints its argument, but it's return value is always `nil`:

```
> val = (puts "Hello World")
Hello World
=> nil
> val
=> nil
```

In your code, the return value of `large` is always nil, so the comparison with a `string` always returns `false`.

This is  probably closer to what you want:

```
def large(string)
  if string.size > 20
    string.upcase!
  else
    string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`puts` prints on screen AND returns `nil`. `nil` and `false` in Ruby, in a boolean context, are `false`. Everything else is `true`. So your method `large`returns `nil`. You should write it like this

```
def large(string)
    if string.size > 20
        string.upcase!
    else
        string
    end
end
```

A better way would be

```
def large(string)
  string.size > 20 ? string.upcase : string
end
```